# Foreach not recognizing close

Tags: 2013, powershell, import, csv

I am trying to add items to a list from a CSV script. I have imported the code and established the variables and even test to ensure that the SP information is accurate.

The following code does not exit.

> PS C:\Users\sharepoint> foreach ($item in $imp) {
>
> >> $new = $list.items.Add();
>
> >> $new['Title'] = $item.Title;
>
> >> $new['Body'] = $item.SectionTitle;
>
> >> $new['StartDate'] = $item.Started;
>
> >> $new['Assignedto] = $item.ResponsibleTranslate;
>
> >> $new.Update();
>
> >> }
>
> >>
>
> >>

I have selected enter several times and I cannot get the foreach to close.

I have tested foreach using "Foreach ($item in $imp) {echo $item}. This works properly.

It only decides to not work when I am trying to reference the information.

Comment: Can you use ISE and add a breakpoint on $new.Update()? It might give you a better idea of what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be because of this: `$new['Assignedto] = $item.ResponsibleTranslate;`

The internal name of the Assigned To column would be `$new['AssignedTo'] = $item.ResponsibleTranslate;`, you are also missing the closing apostrophe.